# Thinkpad L13 Yoga onscreen-keyboard stops working

Tags: 20.04, thinkpad, onscreen-keyboard, yoga-2

Thinkpad L13 Yoga G2 running Ubuntu 20.04 when flipped like this:
[image: L13 Yoga]

screen keyboard **sometimes** stops working properly: "Space", "Delete" keys are not functioning. If I return to normal notebook orientation it starts working again.
What's wrong? Maybe there is an option to replace keyboard software? I tried "Onboard" but it doesn't have other languages and appear together with built-in keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to go this way:

1. Disable built-in screen keyboard via [a Gnome Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3222/block-caribou-36/).
2. Use the "Onboard" keyboard, opened from status bar icon. Found out that to switch language, you have to repeat the keys on physical keyboard (i.e. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>)

There is also an option to improve the built-in keyboard with [this extension (not tested)](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3330/improved-onscreen-keyboard/https://github.com/SebastianLuebke/improved-osk-gnome-ext).